# I installed prestashop via installtron on godaddy and need to set it up but it shows me error 500

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, prestashop

I dont know what im doing wrong, I would like to set it up, and modify it and I would like to know if I could use bootstrap instead of a theme because I have the store already coded in a separate file using bootstrap, thanks in advance. I would like some asessment.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in /home/hkv4puyykily/public_html/classes/db/DbQuery.php:70 Stack trace: #0 /home/hkv4puyykily/public_html/classes/ObjectModel.php(198): DbQueryCore->from('shop', 'a') #1 /home/hkv4puyykily/public_html/classes/shop/Shop.php(131): ObjectModelCore->__construct('1', NULL, NULL) #2 /home/hkv4puyykily/public_html/classes/shop/Shop.php(385): ShopCore->__construct('1') #3 /home/hkv4puyykily/public_html/config/config.inc.php(95): ShopCore::initialize() #4 /home/hkv4puyykily/public_html/index.php(27): require('/home/hkv4puyyk...') #5 {main} thrown in /home/hkv4puyykily/public_html/classes/db/DbQuery.php on line 70

Comment: Turn on DEBUG mode https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/224525-how-to-turn-on-error-reporting-for-debug-information-blank-page-500-internal-server-error/

Comment: I updated it with the error

Comment: Is that a clean PS installation? It is a strange error, i guess when PS tries to instantiate shop object. Ask for support to your hosting. PS 1.7 implements bootstrap and you can customize themes like explains in http://www.prestabrain.com/customize-prestashop-theme-1-7/

Comment: Downgrade your PHP version to 7.2